# Disable for good VIM's number increment that is mapped to Ctrl-a

Tags: vim, tmux

I am using local and remote tmux sessions.
To send commands to the local tmux I use `Ctrl-a`, and to the remote `Ctrl-q`.
I have tried to disable the number increment that normally executes with `Ctrl-a` in vim, but it now triggers with `Ctrl-q` and i cannot find a way  to disable it.
BTW this happens only when a particular tmux window does not nest a remote one.
Also, I think there still might be a combination of shortcuts in a remote tmux session that also triggers the increment.

**So is there a way to completely disable the function?**
An ideal solution would be to override it with a function that does nothing.
That's a very sneaky command, and I had some really terrible debugging experiences in the past because of this!

**My tmux.conf:**

```
..
unbind C-b
set -g prefix C-a
bind-key -n C-q send-prefix
...
```

Then in vim I try to disable both Ctrl-a and Ctrl-q with no-ops.

**This is my vimrc:**

```
...
map <Ctrl-A> <Nop>
map <Ctrl-Q> <Nop>
...
```

I have also tried putting entries for `Ctrl-a` and `Ctrl-q` but still `Ctrl-q` does the increment.
I think the problem is because tmux receives `Ctrl-q` and then sends it as prefix which is somehow not caught by my extra mappings.

Cheers,
Paschalis

Comment: `<C-a>` works for me (`<Ctrl-A>` doesn't). BTW you'll probably want `nnoremap` instead of `map`.

Comment: I read the answer, and then I noticed that you have recommended `C` instead of `Ctrl`! For some reason I though that you have changed just the capital a to lowercase!

Comment: This increment feature is (IMO) terrible to have enabled by default. It seems designed to insidiously introduce errors in data... like when I was using Vim to quickly change the format of a list of hundreds of UUIDs, and discovered that along the way I had accidentally incremented numbers in a few of them. Gah!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Why it doesn't work

`Ctrl` is not a vim-recognized `<>` notation to represent a keyboard's <kbd>Control</kbd> key.

### Recommendation

To disable <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> triggering default vim auto-increment on a number:

1. In your `~/.vimrc`, as @Marth said, use `<C-a>`:

   ```
   map <C-a> <Nop>
   ```
2. Save `:w`
3. `:so ~/.vimrc` for it to take effect.

### Warranty

- Tested to work in Vim 7.4
- You don't need to disable Ctrl-q in Vim

### Explanation

- Don't need to disable Ctrl-q within Vim, since your Tmux is never sending Ctrl-q,
- Your posted `tmux.conf` is sending prefix, which you define as Ctrl-a, so Vim is only receiving Ctrl-a

Thus you successfully disable the auto-increment when you map <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> to the do-nothing instruction `<Nop>`

### Further reading

- Vim, `:help <>`

Comment: BTW I really like the format of your answer! thanks!

Comment: Thank you! You posted a well-formatted, complete question to begin with, definitely helped.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I could still (accidentally) trigger the unwanted increment/decrement behavior from visual mode with <kbd>g</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd>. I patched this case by adding this to my .vimrc (extending the answer above):

```
map <C-a> <Nop>
map g<C-a> <Nop>
map <C-x> <Nop>
map g<C-x> <Nop>
```