# Disable timeout on esc key

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

## Problem

I am in `insert mode`, and then I might type a number, and then quickly <kbd>ESC</kbd>, because I stopped typing so it will change to `visual mode`.
What happens then, is that the `cursor` jumps, and not only that, the number on the line that I was (and I just typed) is decremented.
This thing is a nightmare!

## What is causing this?

Is this some kind of default behavior? If so, how can I disable it?
Could this be a plugin causing it? Because I didn't always had this "feature".
I was trying for some months to figure out what is causing this, and I've posted this [generic question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43777178/vim-find-history-of-recently-used-shortcuts).

Especially when programming, number auto-decrement can cause lot of headaches, so I've disabled the default mapping for it, by mapping `<C-a> <Nop>` in my `.vimrc`; more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36601789/disable-for-good-vims-number-increment-that-is-mapped-to-ctrl-a).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue seems linked to the `'timeout'` option, and its friends `'timeoutlen'`, `'ttimeout'`, `'ttimeoutlen'`.

Try this command:

```
:set timeout timeoutlen=3000 ttimeoutlen=100
```

It's taken from `:h 'ttm`:

> The timeout only happens when the 'timeout' and 'ttimeout' options
>     tell so.  A useful setting would be         :set timeout timeoutlen=3000
>   ttimeoutlen=100   (time out on mapping after three seconds, time out
>   on key codes after    a tenth of a second).

---

Personally,  I use these settings:

```
set timeout
set ttimeout
set timeoutlen=3000
set ttimeoutlen=50
```

The first 2 commands enable a timeout on mappings and keycodes respectively.

The 3rd command `set timeoutlen=3000` tells Vim to wait `3s` to let me finish typing the left-hand-side of a mapping.

The 4th command `set ttimeoutlen=50` tells Vim to only wait `50ms` for a sequence of keycodes to finish. For example, on my machine, `F1` produces the sequence of keycodes `Escape O P` (confirmed by typing `C-v F1` in insert mode, which displays `^[OP`; `^[` stands for `Escape`).

It's possible that your original issue comes from the fact that the value of your `'ttimeoutlen'` option is too high, and therefore the timeout for a sequence of keycodes doesn't occur soon enough, allowing Vim to sometimes interpret a sequence of keystrokes you type as produced by some other key you didn't press. By reducing its value, you may prevent this.

---

If your issue persists even though you set the previous options in your `vimrc`, it's possible that a plugin changes them afterwards.

In this case, when your issue occurs again, type these commands:

```
:verb set timeout?
:verb set ttimeout?
:verb set timeoutlen?
:verb set ttimeoutlen?
```

Each of them will tell you the current value of your options, but more importantly it will tell you the name of the last file which changed the value.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. When I started using `vim` I used other people's popular `vimrc`s, and since then I slowly removed most of that crap. I still have some leftovers in a `legacy.vim` file and the issue was coming from there!

Comment: Still got some of those issues. Numbers are fixed, but still have to reproduce the others.

Comment: @Paschalis Ah sorry about that. If you can reproduce your other issues, you could ask another question, and maybe someone will find a solution. If possible, try to reproduce it with a minimum of sourced files and a minimal `vimrc` (`vim -Nu my_short_vimrc`). There are many options in Vim, maybe one of them is not configured like it should. Have a look at the `:opt` command. It should open a window where most (all?) options are displayed, and sorted by category. It's an interactive window, so you can temporarily change their values from there.